# What is the right way to prepopulate array in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb

MongoDB documentation says that growing arrays is slow and one should minimize or eliminate it whenever possible. I have an array of subdocuments (let's say these are comments to blog post):

```
comments = [ {name : "E.D.", date : "2013.03.20", text : "awesome stuff!"},
             {name : "J.L.", date : "2013.03.21", text : "tl;dr"} ]
```

and it will grow quite predictably, so I think it should be prepopulated from the beginning for efficiency. But do I need to create subdocuments itself:

```
### I Version
comments = [ { },
             { } ]
```

or is it enough to just initialize array with zeroes?

```
### II Version
comments = [ 0,
             0 ]
```

(And of course I should keep track of how many comments there actually were left by visitors.)

"Comments" can be up to few KB in size, does that have any impact on document growth? Maybe I should create placeholders of the same size as max allowed text?

```
### III Version
comments = [ {name : "Name Surname", date : "1970.01.01", text : "this is a placeholder"},
             {name : "Name Surname", date : "1970.01.01", text : "this is a placeholder"} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-populating with empty hashes or zeroes has no sense: when you will insert real data, the document will expand.

Your third version looks more like it. Although it seems to be non-trivial to clear dummy data when inserting real comments.

You could alternatively insert a sufficiently large chunk of text into a special field and remove it later, upon comment insertion. Something like this:

```
db.posts.insert({
  comments: [],
  padding: 'lorep ipsum ... x N'
})


db.posts.update(query, 
                {$push: {comments: comment_data},
                 $unset: padding})
```